# canvas not working when using margin

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Im developing a drwaing app with canvas.
I have some basic html like:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="toolbar">
      some tools...
    </ul> 
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="420" height="420"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS for `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper { width: 490px }
```

The JS:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        drawPixel(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        drawPixel(e.pageX, e.pageY);
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
    });

var drawPixel = function (x, y) {
    if (! canvas.isDrawing) {
        return;
    }

    x = (Math.ceil(x / 15) * 15 ) - 15;
    y = (Math.ceil(y / 15) * 15 ) - 15;

    context.fillStyle = pixelColor;

    if (pixelColor === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
        context.clearRect(x, y, 15, 15);
    } else {
        context.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
    }
```

Now everything works like expected, i can draw some lines on my canvas but when i add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.wrapper` i cant draw anymore dont know why?

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'll remove my -1 when you post the JavaScript involved with drawing

Comment: added a livedemo

Comment: No, the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Again: Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the pixels onto the canvas only relative to the page/document itself, not to the canvas element. That's why it works when the canvas is positionned in the top left corner but not when the canvas is located anywhere else on the page.

Only a minor fix is needed to make it work. You will need to update both event listeners which draw on the canvas and substract the offset positions of the canvas, like so:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    drawPixel(e.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left, e.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    drawPixel(e.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left, e.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top);
    canvas.isDrawing = false;
});
```